# Is it better to return by value for small types for getters in traits?

Tags: rust, reference, return-value, traits, getter

For most data types, I follow the convention in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35391084/11963778 and have getters returning references:

```rust
trait HasName {
    fn name(&self) -> &String;
    fn name_mut(&mut self) -> &mut String;
}
```

However, for data types that have copy semantics and are smaller than (or around the size of) a pointer, should I have a getter method returning the value instead? It would look something like this:

```rust
trait HasNum {
    fn num_v(&self) -> i32;
    fn num(&self) -> &i32;
    fn num_mut(&mut self) -> &mut i32;
}
```

Is it good practice to have a getter that returns the value instead? If so, then up to what size should I do this for small data types?

Comment: [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423) applies to `&String` as a return value.

Answer (score 3):

As a rule of thumb you can copy values held on a single cache line instead of using references. While cache lines are typically 64bytes on x86, Intel recommends limiting data to 16 bytes to reduce the chance of the value not being aligned.

So in other words, its probably fine to just copy anything around the size of `[i32; 4]` or less.

***Note:** While there is some reasoning behind it, I just made this rule up based on what I know about performance so far. If enough people were to look at this post, I'm sure someone else will have a better answer. That being said, even if my reasoning is a bit off I think it will likely still hold up in most cases when you aren't trying to optimize an extremely time critical piece of code or for a specific CPU.*

In the time I spent writing this answer I also found a few more interesting points in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40185665/performance-cost-of-passing-by-value-vs-by-reference-or-by-pointer).

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/40185996/5987669

  > It is common, for example, for a machine to have an architecture (machine registers, memory architecture, etc) which result in a "sweet spot" - copying variables of some size is most "efficient", but copying larger OR SMALLER variables is less so. Larger variables will cost more to copy, because there may be a need to do multiple copies of smaller chunks. Smaller ones may also cost more, because the compiler needs to copy the smaller value into a larger variable (or register), do the operations on it, then copy the value back.
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/49523201/5987669 
  *This answer is specific to C, but I wouldn't be surprised if it applied to Rust as well*

  > There is a certain GCC optimization called IPA SRA, that replaces "pass by reference" with "pass by value" automatically: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html (-fipa-sra)
  >
  > ...
  > So with this optimization enabled, using references for small types should be as fast as passing them by value.
  > On the other hand passing (for example) std::string by value could not be optimized to by-reference speed, as custom copy semantics are being involved.