# Creating a Rust useState-like function to get and set state using closures

Tags: rust, state

I am trying to implement a useState-like function in Rust. I mean, a function that takes a value and returns its state as well as a function to modify it. I know that this is possible using setter and getter in something like OO for Rust([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35390615/writing-getter-setter-properties-in-rust)). But, I am trying to do it using closures inside a function. How can I achieve this?

This is my try:

```
fn use_state<T: Copy>(value: T) -> (impl Fn() -> T, impl FnMut(T)) {
    let mut val: T = value;

    let state = move || -> T { val };

    let set_state = move |v: T| {
        val = v;
    };
    (state, set_state)
}

fn main() {
    let (counter, mut set_counter) = use_state(0);
    println!("{:?}", counter()); // 0

    set_counter(1);
    println!("{:?}", counter()); // 0 but I expected 1

}
```

I managed to do this in Typescript([here](https://github.com/programandoconro/Programming-Locker/blob/master/Languages/Typescript/Generics/useState.ts)), but I do not know how to implement it in Rust. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You copy the value to each closure, meaning they don't share it. When one will change its value, the other won't be affected.

You need to use [reference counting](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/index.html) to share the value, with [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/) to change the value behind:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::Cell;

fn use_state<T: Copy>(value: T) -> (impl Fn() -> T, impl FnMut(T)) {
    let val = Rc::new(Cell::new(value));

    let state = {
        let val = Rc::clone(&val);
        move || -> T { val.get() }
    };

    let set_state = move |v: T| {
        val.set(v);
    };
    (state, set_state)
}
```